# Make content expand and collapse when using the Microsoft Ribbon for WPF

Tags: wpf, user-interface, ribbon

I don't understand how to get the [default ribbon minimization behavior shown in MS Word](http://screencast.com/t/qj1SB8guHukB) in my app (using [MS Ribbon for WPF](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Ribbon%20Preview)). (Specifically, when the ribbon is minimized, the content area moves up to fill the space that the ribbon previously filled.)

If I just put an element in the Grid containing my Ribbon, [it doesn't automatically move to fill the space when the ribbon is minimized](http://screencast.com/t/sNX89VJ6i6Q).

Any pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's funny how you can search and search, then when you finally ask the question you find the answer yourself.

It's as simple as putting the ribbon in a Grid with two Rows, the top with `Height="Auto"` and the bottom with `Height="*"`. See http://wpf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=39958. The trick is to remember to add the `Grid.Row` property to the ribbon and your content control.